# Which of the following would be a way to start a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery

```
$.fn.plugin = function() {this.css(“color”,”black”);}; 

function plugin() { this.css(“color”,”black”); };

var plugin = function( a, b ) { this.css(“color”,”black”); };

$.plugin = function() {this.css(“color”,”black”);}; 

${}.plugin = function() {this.css(“color”,”black”);};
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Some notes: 1) `$.fn.plugin` and `$.plugin` mean *different* things.  They are both "plugins" but they are not the same.  `$.fn` is just shorthand for `jQuery.prototype` so that will add methods to jQuery objects (elements) whereas `$.plugin` is ran on its own, not on a jQuery object.  2) `${}.plugin` is a syntax error.  3)  You need to assign a function to either `$.fn.plugin` or `$.plugin` depending on what you want to do.  Whether you use `function plugin()` or `var plugin = function()` doesn't really matter (it depends on how your code is structured).